# How to traverse through HashSet of objects and print the String value of each object in ToString method?

Tags: java, hashset

```
HashSet<Soldier> soldiers;           // it has name, rank, description

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Team: " + teamName + "\n" + "Rank: " + getRanking(soldiers) + "\n" 
     + "Team Members Names are: "+"\n" + soldiers.iterator().hasNext();
    //last line doesn't work
    // I also tried soldiers.forEach(System.out::println) but doesn't work
}
```

Can anyone please how I can print all the name from Hashset in overriden toString method. Thanks

Comment: `soldiers.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`.

Comment: Or simply `soldiers`, although that would print `[andy, ben, chris]`.

Comment: Simply `String.join(", ", soldiers)` will do.

Comment: @AndyTurner how can I only print each string value in soldiers not the whole object. is that make sense? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **java 8**. It's simple to do with **stream API**:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();

        strings.add("111");
        strings.add("113");
        strings.add("112");
        strings.add("114");

        String contactString = strings.stream().map(String::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }
    
}
```

If you want change a delimiter you should replace `Collectiors.joining(",")` code to what you need. See also documentation by [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)

For your class `Soldier` which has method `getName()`:

```
Set<Soldier> soldiers = new HashSet<>();
String soldierNames = soldiers.stream().map(Soldier::getName).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

You will get a next result:

> Din
>
> Mark
>
> David
>
> ... values from the soldiers set

Comment: I have three different String values in the set. I just wanted print first String value that is the name of the soldier. I can access the name of the soldier with getName() method. Also I want to print each name in new line.

Comment: @Reboot use `Soldier::getName` in place of `String::toString`.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner

Answer (score 0):

hasNext() does only return a boolean indicating if the Iterator is finished or not.
You still have to call next() (in a loop) to get the next value(s).
See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html